# Laravel backpack demo install 404 error for all created pages

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a brand new install of backpack for laravel using the demo git project. Everything installed without error. Unfortunately every page I create becomes a 404 not found error. I would appreciate any help regarding where to look first. Again this is a vanilla install, nothing else configured.

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to create these pages? Specifically, seeing the routes you've created, the code for loading those routes, and the urls you're attempting to hit in the browser to access the pages.

Comment: Also, you could run `php artisan route:list` and check the output there. This will tell you if the expected routes are even being registered and show you if the urls are something other than what you expect.